# Authorization and Authentication attribute where the permissions have to take from database in MVC5

Tags: authentication, authorization, dynamic-programming, identity, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC application I want to give a privilege to super-admin to give the authorization of various modules in the application. For this I have 3 tables:

1. Roles,
2. Permissions (i.e View, Create, Alter, Delete) (and this stores ModuleID and Permissions),
3. ModuleMaster (which stores ControllerName, ActionName).

Now I want to filter every controller and its action as it has the permission in the permission table. And for this I have to get the value from the database and then have to send to the attribute.

But I am not getting anything for this dynamic authorization facility.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution for my question.
I did this by adding new attribute named as attest which inherits AuthorizeAttribute and then Overriding OnAuthorization.
First i made a class in which i checked whether the particular user has the permission to access the called Action in particular controller which return true or false .
Then i called this in AttestAttribute if the user role has the permission for particular action then normal functioning will performed but if its not,then you can redirect it to Error page.

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var parameters = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
        var values = parameters.Select(s => new
        {
            Name = s.ParameterName,
            Value = filterContext.HttpContext.Request[s.ParameterName]
        });

        string ControlerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        AppUser requestingUser = new AppUser(Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["ssnRolekey"]));
        if (!requestingUser.HasPermission(oper, ControlerName))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                           new RouteValueDictionary { 
                                            { "action", "UnauthorizedUser" }, 
                                            { "controller", "Account" } });
            }
    }

    public AttestAttribute( string permission)
    {
       this.oper = permission;
    }
```